# Prevent mouse click from changing cursor position while in insert mode

Tags: evil, mouse

I work on a laptop most of the time and it happens somewhat often that while inserting some text (in evil mode) I will accidentally hit the touchpad with my thumb, changing the cursor position and causing the next few words to be inserted into some unrelated paragraph. The somewhat annoying thing is that undo is usually of no help here, because the last saved undo state is whenever I entered insert mode and I might have written several sentences since then that I don't want to lose. I'd rather not completely disable use of the mouse, so I'm hoping to implement one of the following acceptable fixes:

- Don't allow mouse clicks to change position while in evil insert mode, only in normal mode (this sounds the simplest).
- Update the undo state whenever I change cursor position with the mouse, if there is a callback for that.

Are either of these possible?

Comment: The function `undo-boundary` looks like it might be helpful if you call it when setting point with the mouse ....  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Undo.html  My recollection is that there is more than one mouse-set-point related functions, so it may depend upon the mode.  You can type `C-h k` and see what your mouse click is bound to.

Comment: If you run a terminal specific build of emacs (`emacs-nox`) the mouse clicks will never have any effect (except to shift focus to your window).  That's not what you asked for - but this is only a comment, not an answer.

Comment: AFAIK the undo behavior you describe only kicks in after you exit insert mode: while in insert mode, undo should be able to undo just the last few chars inserted rather than undo all the way to the state where you entered insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

I appended this to my `.emacs` to disable the changing of point (cursor) on tap:
`(defun mouse-set-point (event))`

What it does is basically it changes the definition of the `mouse-set-point` function to nothing so that the function does not change the point (position in the buffer).

If you want to go back to the default definition, remove the line or uncomment it.

This will sometimes make the clicking of the link hard so fiddle with the variable: `mouse-1-click-follows-link` to see what suits you best.

Comment: It is EXACTLY what I needed. Cursor works all works, menu with mouse works... but I cannot change position in a document which I never needed! Thanks! That's really a big help!

Answer (score 0):

Two potential answers:

1) This is not exactly an emacs fix for your question, and may or may not apply in your situation. The exact steps will depend on your os and desktop environment:

If you're using linux with one of many desktop environments (gnome3, MATE, openbox, etc.) there is a setting under "mouse" settings (sometimes on the "touchpad" tab of the mouse-settings window) that says something to the effect of "disable touchpad while typing" (see also "synaptic"). This will not help if you pause typing and then touch the touchpad.

2) emacs solution: Stolen directly from: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/a799um/how_to_disable_mouse_in_emacs/

This involves setting the keybinding for the mouse to do nothing (nil):

```
(use-package evil
  :ensure t
  :diminish evil
  :init (evil-mode 1)
  (setq evil-insert-state-cursor '((bar . 1) "white")
  evil-visual-state-cursor '(box "dark orange")
  evil-normal-state-cursor '(box "white"))
  :bind (:map
   evil-insert-state-map
   ([S-left]     . windmove-left)
   ([S-right]    . windmove-right)
   ([S-up]     . windmove-up)
   ([S-down]    . windmove-down)
   ("<down-mouse-1>" . nil)
   ("<mouse-1>" . nil)
   ("<down-mouse-3>" . nil)
   ("<mouse-3>" . nil)
   ("SPC" . nil)
   :map
   evil-normal-state-map
   (";" . evil-ex)
   (":"   .       evil-repeat-find-char)
   ("<down-mouse-1>" . nil)
   ("<mouse-1>" . nil)
   ("<down-mouse-3>" . nil)
   ("<mouse-3>" . nil)
   ("SPC" . nil)
   :map    evil-motion-state-map
   ([S-left]     . windmove-left)
   ([S-right]    . windmove-right)
   ([S-up]     . windmove-up)
   ([S-down]    . windmove-down)
   ("<down-mouse-1>" . nil)
   ("<mouse-1>" . nil)
   ("<down-mouse-3>" . nil)
   ("<mouse-3>" . nil)
   ("SPC" . nil)
   ))
```